# Can't install Ubuntu 20.04 along Windows 11 in Alienware x17 R2 laptop (dual boot)

Tags: drivers, dual-boot, 20.04, partitioning, nvidia

I just bought an Alienware x17 R2 laptop that has these specifications:

**Display:** `17.3" UHD (3840 x 2160) 120Hz 3ms with ComfortView Plus, NVIDIA G-SYNC and Advanced Optimus`
**Hard Drive:** `1TB M.2 PCIe NVMe Solid State Drive`
**Memory:** `32GB (2x16GB) DDR5 4800MHz`
**Operating System:** `Windows 11 Home, English`
**Processor:** `12th Gen Intel Core i9-12900H 14-Core Processor (24M Cache, up to 5.0 GHz Max Turbo Frequency)`
**Video Card:** `NVIDIA(R) GeForce RTX(TM) 3070 Ti 8GB GDDR6`
**Wireless:** `Killer(TM) Wi-Fi 6 (6E* Pre-certified) AX1675 802.11ax 2x2 Wireless LAN and Bluetooth 5.2`

The current OS is Windows 11 and I am trying to install Ubuntu 20.04 and make it dual boot. For some reasons the format is not working properly.

I disabled secure boot in bios. I formatted ubuntu ios image on both, USB 2.0 and USB 3.0 using Rufus. I even disabled "Turn on fast startup" option in Control Panel > Power Option. I created a new partition with unallocated space.

When I try to install Ubuntu, the option "Download updates while installing Ubuntu" is disabled and the installation process does not ask to connect with the wifi.[link to image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qRPM.jpg)

I continue the installation and after it says the installation is completed, I restart my laptop to open Ubuntu again. It shows me either e black screen or this messages [link to image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NqwvG.jpg)

Can someone please help me how to proceed?

Comment: "Download updates while installing Ubuntu" from your message. Leave this turned on. That may give you the option to install the missing video driver. Your problem sounds like the typical wrong or no video driver for the card in the machine. Did you use the Try Ubuntu before doing install to see if that works?

Comment: Did you verify the ISO before making the boot device. See this site https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-verify-ubuntu#1-overview

Comment: System is too new for 20.04, you need at least 22.04  and may need to update kernel or drivers. My MSI motherboard with 12400 cpu and Samsung NVMe drive just worked with 22.04. I expected more issues, but no WiFi as Ethernet and Intel chip's video. Does 22.04 live installer work in live mode, including WiFi?